# Unknown error on project explorer from eclipse

Tags: android, build, project

I am using eclipse as a development environment. I have several applications that link to one library. After I clean the project and rebuild them. They all compile fine. Once I ran the application, it's display a message saying: My project has errors that require me to fix it. There was an error icon next to the project name under the project explorer but it doesn't show any errors anywhere else.

I wanted to know where i can find out what the error is that causing me the strange behaviour.

Reason why it was strange because I just started up my project that haven't been touched for a while. It worked the last time I worked on it. Don't know why I have strange behaviour after opening the eclipse then make clean up and rebuilt the projects.

Comment: Open the Problems perspective and check where the error is.

Comment: where do find the Problems perspective

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Problems

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 10/05/12 11:49 PM   Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your debug certificate under `~/.android/debug.keystore` on Linux and Mac OS X; the directory is something like `%USERPROFILE%/.android` on Windows.

The Eclipse plugin should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate. To clean the project run `ant clean` or go to `Build -> Clean`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but for a different error and it looks like I had problems with accessing the project directory from within VMware Workstation 10 that was running Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9 and I was getting hidden folders named ".AppleDouble" . Please notice there is a DOT at the start of ".AppleDouble" . just delete the the folders! The project will go back as it was and work perfectly.